@Component Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when using vue-decorator
I am using vue3 with vue-facing-decorator but when running dev server i am seeing error in console that  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on @Component
Here is my package.json
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.2.6",
    "vue": "^3.5.12",
    "vue-facing-decorator": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node22": "^22.0.0",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.7",
    "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.1.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^4.0.1",
    "@vitest/eslint-plugin": "1.1.7",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^10.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^14.1.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.6",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.1",
    "eslint": "^9.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.30.0",
    "jsdom": "^25.0.1",
    "npm-run-all2": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "~5.6.3",
    "vite": "^5.4.10",
    "vite-plugin-vue-devtools": "^7.5.4",
    "vitest": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.1.10"
  }
  }
}


tsConfig https://pastebin.com/3eTq4X4W
My component where i am using vue-facing-decorator.
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, toNative } from "vue-facing-decorator";

@Component
class Workflow extends Vue {
  getState() {
    return "";
  }
}

export default toNative(Workflow);
</script>

I tries adding "experimentalDecorators": true, also look into https://facing-dev.github.io/vue-facing-decorator/#/.

Contrary to what the authors of vue-facing-decorator are claiming, it is not "official recommended". In fact, if you open that link on their page you can clearly read: "The recommended way to use Vue 3 in large applications is Single-File Components, Composition API, and <script setup>".

Yep, agreed on this being not official. I am building a very small project and thought using this plugin will make my life easier to write components.

Since it's not officially supported, expect this plugin not to work with latest version of Vue and allow its developers time for updates. Should work with a lower version (e.g: 3.4).
